# Neo4j with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, neo4j

I need your help to the knowledge on Neo4j with .net, I am trying to integrate Neo4j along with .net application and want to perform CRUD operations on that data. My primary question would be ,

1. Is Neo4j supports .Net Entity Framework like we do with SQL server ?
2. Can we create and call stored procedures like we do in SQL

Thanks in advance, Please help me on the above questions

Thanks
Ram

Comment: any updates on this question?